# Update the already included records

Tags: cloud, salesforce, apex-code

I have two objects fromUpdated and toBeUpdated. Both the objects have two fields aField and bField. I have to write a code such that when a new record is inserted in toBeUpdated . It checks if the record has been already there previously. The key which is cheked is aField and if the aField is a match between two records then it just updates the another field bField without creating a new record for the toBeUpated object.

After this operation i also have to delete all the objects from the fromUpdate object.

I know query and delete() would provide this functionality but how to write a SOQL statement for this functionality is what i cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to do you write a SOQL query to do the delete and the update, the answer is you can't. SOQL is quite different to SQL in many respects, and the way to do 3 different operations.

1. First find matching records that you need to update using a SOQL query
2. Perform an `upsert` operation to insert new lines and update existing records after modifying `bField` in code
3. Delete the records you need to delete from the `fromUpdate` object

A delete is as you've stated yourself: query and then delete.

Of course, to keep the code succinct you can just do this in a one liner:

```
delete [select Id from MyObject__c where SomeField = true];
```

Comment: one thing, this cannot be done directly in the apex code in the developer console, Right ?? and this should be writtren in Java/C# and then SOAP API should be used to make it visible to the apex code. Please correct me if i am wrong here . Thansk Matt

Comment: You can run one off jobs from the developer console, it's remarkably handy for simple data jobs when you know what you're doing. It sounds to me like you really want to write an apex trigger on the toBeUpdated object, which runs before insert (see the docs: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_invoking.htm) — that said this my not be correct for your scenario, it's hard to tell with the details provided.